# how can i set a range of numbers for this function

Tags: jquery

I need to add a range so that franchise_id 0000-0096 is used instead of franchise_id=="0000"

in else , i need to apply the jQuery to all franchise , NOT 0000-00096 , and also to all who have no franchise_id if found at all

```
if(franchise_id=="0000") {
  $("#source_list > option[value*='MESSAGE']").show();
  $("h3 a:contains('Skin')").show();
  $("#options_01 a:contains('Skin')").show();
} else {
  $("#source_list > option[value*='MESSAGE']").remove();
  $("h3 a:contains('Skin')").remove();
  $("#options_01 a:contains('Skin')").remove();
}
```

Comment: means u want to check franchise_id is in between 0000-0096 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alot of other ways. You can use RegEx too.
Here is one simple solution:

```
if(franchise_id >= parseInt("0000") || franchise_id<=parseInt("0096")){
    //do something
}
```

**EDIT**

// first check if franchise_id exists. If it doesn't, apply the else condtion

```
if((typeof franchise_id !== 'undefined') && (franchise_id >= parseInt("0000") || franchise_id<=parseInt("0096"))){
    //do something
}else{
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: have a follow up what if franchise_id doesn't exit , how can i add the else to apply to all franchise_id not covered by the if , and when franchise_id not detected at all ?

Comment: You can check if franchise_id exists or not. And it doesn't exist you can define what to do in the else block.